# JSX instead of HTML in Sweet Alert

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, sweetalert2

I would like to write JSX in Sweet Alert like so:

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component { 
  componentDidMount() {
    swal({
      html: <Welcome />
    });
  };

  render() {
    return <Welcome />;
  }
}

const Welcome = (props) => <p>Welcome to Sweet Alert and React</p>;

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

But I get `Uncaught TypeError: t.html.cloneNode is not a function` error.

How can I write JSX in Sweet Alert html?

Comment: Rewrite the parts of Sweet Alert that process that data

Comment: @Quentin But how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/)

> In order to use SweetAlert with JSX syntax, you need to install SweetAlert with React. Note that you need to have both sweetalert and @sweetalert/with-react as dependencies in your package.json.

You need to install `@sweetalert/with-react`,

```
npm install @sweetalert/with-react --save
```

Import

```
import swal from '@sweetalert/with-react'
```

And Usage

```
swal(<Welcome />) //No need of `html` key
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-vuu2g?fontsize=14)

Comment: Since it doesn't work with new version of React, is there any other similar solution for React > v17 ?